# ANTLR4: Using non-ASCII characters in token rules

Tags: unicode, antlr, token, grammar, antlr4

On page 74 of the ANTRL4 book it says that any Unicode character can be used in a grammar simply by specifying its codepoint in this manner:

```
'\uxxxx'
```

where `xxxx` is the hexadecimal value for the Unicode codepoint.

So I used that technique in a token rule for an ID token:

```
grammar ID;

id : ID EOF ;

ID : ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '\u0100' .. '\u017E')+ ;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

When I tried to parse this input:

```
Gŭnter
```

ANTLR throws an error, saying that it does not recognize `ŭ`. (The ŭ character is hex 016D, so it is within the range specified)

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 11):

ANTLR is ready to accept 16-bit characters but, by default, many locales will read in characters as bytes (8 bits). You need to specify the appropriate encoding when you read from the file using the Java libraries. If you are using the `TestRig`, perhaps through alias/script `grun`, then use argument `-encoding utf-8` or whatever. If you look at the source code of that class, you will see the following mechanism:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is, encoding); // e.g., euc-jp or utf-8
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(r);
XLexer lexer = new XLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
...
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried adding the -encoding flag when invoking TestRig:
java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig -encoding UTF-8 ID.g4
However, that resulted in this error : 
Can't load -encoding as lexer or parser
Suggestions?

Comment: you don't use TestRig on your grammar. that is what antlr is for.

Comment: Hi! Still no success. Here's what I did: (1) java org.antlr.v4.Tool -encoding UTF-8 ID.g4 (2) javac *.java  (3) java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig ID id -gui < input.txt ... That resulted in a series of "token recognition" errors. Suggestions?

Comment: -encoding goes on grun per my answer

Comment: Ah, yes that was a typo. Here's the command that I actually ran: java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig -encoding UTF-8 ID id -gui < input.txt Again, as before, that resulted in this error : Can't load -encoding as lexer or parser. Suggestions?

Comment: `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig ID ...`

Comment: Thanks Gunther. I gave that a go, but it gives the same error message: Can't load -encoding as lexer or parser.

Comment: Even though this is a year late, it might help someone as it helped me. It says "Can't load -encoding as lexer or parser." because the name of you parser/lexer has to go right after org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig. It is now trying to find the lexer/parser named '-encoding'. The correct command is "java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig grammarName -encoding UTF-8 startRule input.txt"

Answer (score 4):

For those having the same problem using antlr4 in java code, `ANTLRInputStream` beeing deprecated, here is a working way to pass multi-char unicode data from a `String` to a the `MyLexer` lexer  :

```java
String myString = "\u2013";

CharBuffer charBuffer = CharBuffer.wrap(myString.toCharArray());
CodePointBuffer codePointBuffer = CodePointBuffer.withChars(charBuffer);
CodePointCharStream cpcs = CodePointCharStream.fromBuffer(codePointBuffer);

OneLexer lexer = new MyLexer(cpcs);       
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
```

Answer (score 4):

Grammar:

```antlr
NAME:
   [A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z\u0080-\uFFFF_]+
;
```

Java:

```java
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.TokenStream;

final class RequirementParser {

   static SystemContext parse( String requirement ) {
      requirement = requirement.replaceAll( "\t", "   " );
      final CharStream     charStream = CharStreams.fromString( requirement );
      final StimulusLexer  lexer      = new StimulusLexer( charStream );
      final TokenStream    tokens     = new CommonTokenStream( lexer );
      final StimulusParser parser     = new StimulusParser( tokens );
      final SystemContext  system     = parser.system();
      if( parser.getNumberOfSyntaxErrors() > 0 ) {
         Debug.format( requirement );
      }
      return system;
   }

   private RequirementParser() {/**/}
}
```

Source:

[Lexers and Unicode text](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/unicode.md)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the encoding of the file when actually reading the file.
For Kotlin/Java that could look like this, no need to specify the encoding in the grammar!

```
val inputStream: CharStream = CharStreams.fromFileName(fileName, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"))
val lexer = BlastFeatureGrammarLexer(inputStream)
```

[Supported Charsets by Java/Kotlin](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)